# How to replace a JavaScript function (which is loaded -among other code- from a remote file) with my own implementation using Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

There's a page eg. `http://somesite.com` that runs some javascript code located in path eg.`http://somesite.com/code.js`

In that file -among other code- there's a function (`badFunction(x,y)`).

I'd like to change the value of one of it's local variables, in order to make it equal with some another (local) variable (which is used inside in *another* function, also located in that remote javascript file).

So, based on these two answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176955/3231411) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23479894/3231411) (i.e [this userscript](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/125936)), 
I've tried the following simple userscript, in order to replace the entire `badFunction` with my own implementation, but it doesn't work  (i.e my `badFunction` is not injected in the loaded `code.js` - I've checked it via Firefox's Debugger).

What I'm trying to accomplish with the userscript, is, while the `code.js` is loaded, at the time the `badFunction` definition is reached, to inject my function implementation, and then, let the rest `code.js` continue it's loading normally.

What is wrong in my userscript? Or is my approach wrong altogether?

*I'd prefer not give the actual URL of the forementioned remote javascript file as it's NSFW.*

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           @document-start Example
// @version        1
// @namespace      
// @include        http://somesite.com/*
// @run-at         document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var changed = 1; // script need to be edited with

window.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', function(e) {

  ///for external script:   
    src = e.target.src;
    if (src.search(/code\.js/) == "badFunction") {
        changed--;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        append(badFunction);
    };

    ///when done, remove the listener:
    if(changed == 0) window.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee, true);

}, true);


////// append with new block function:
function append(s) {     
    document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script'))
                          .innerHTML = s.toString().replace(/^function.*{|}$/g, '');
}

function badFunction(x, y)
{
 // my code
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading these two answers (which I upvoted of course):
[How to overwrite a function using a userscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21274652/3231411) and
[Stop execution of Javascript function (client side) or tweak it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3974715/3231411)
(and because `badfunction` is not global, and `code.js` fires immediately and is a file, not inline)
the solution I concluded to is:

- First, grab a copy of the script and make the desired change to it.
  Save this locally.
- Then use Adblock Plus to block loading of that
  remote script file.
- Then use the script offered in the 2nd link to
  add my modified local file to the page.

  ```
  var scriptNode = document.createElement ("script");
  scriptNode.setAttribute ("src", "Point to your modified JS file here.");
  document.head.appendChild (scriptNode);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the source code of your site so I do not know how the `badFunction` is declared and called. However keep in mind that if the function is called inside a closure you need to inject the code somewhere inside that closure:

```
(function someClosure() {
  function hello() {
    // code
  }
  // hello is available
})();
// hello is not available
```

In the [link](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/125936) they show how to modify the existing source code

```
window.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', function(e) {

    ///for external script:
    src = e.target.src;
    if (src.search(/bad\.js/) != -1) {
                changed++;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        append(NewScript1);
    };
});
```

So basically you need to search for your function code and replace it. Remember you can search for newlines in regex using `[\s\S]*` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1068308/3384501)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I've misjudged the necessity of the addEventListener. So, I edited my userscript code -I hope I got it right- (btw `badFunction` is not inside a closure). But still it doesn't work. (there's no error in Error Console, but the edited function doesn't seem to be injected)

Comment: I've renamed and edited again my question, to better describe what I'm trying do.

Comment: If overriding `badfunction` doesn't work it means some variable is holding it and that this variable is used for the call because `badfunction` should be overrided. Did you try to call `badFunction` within console after your script loaded ?

BTW  with the example above I was talking about changing the source code before it is actually loaded which is what the page seems to suggest although I am not sure about this technique